# How do I get the duration of time using multiple Dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, date, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord bot, and currently cannot find how to use multiple dates, and make it to where it gives me the minutes:seconds of the total duration of the times.

```js
   { duty: 'on', time: 1589667682669 },
    { duty: 'off', time: 1589667688750 },
    { duty: 'on', time: 1589667692399 },
    { duty: 'off', time: 1589667700338 }
```

I have my code filtering all of the entries to only return if they're `on` duty, and whenever I try to reduce it (using [].reduce), it gives me a wack time.. too much of a wack time.
(50 years ago wack)

```js
            let time = data.tracking.filter(t => t.duty == "on").reduce((prev, current) => {
                return current.time - prev
            }, 0)
```

What can I do to fix this and get the duration of all times the user was marked as on duty?

Comment: So I'm confused, what are you trying todo? get the total of how long the bot was ON duty by combining all the times? or how long it's been ON duty since it's prev OFF duty?

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer I'm trying to get the times the user has been on duty, and get the duration of the times they've been on duty in the whole array. So say I'm marked as on duty 6 times and off duty 7 times. I wanna take the 6 times I've been on duty, and get the duration of it from the first time I was marked on duty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that it's gonna be on-off and you want it to be the amount of time spent on.
Just group it into on/off pairs and get `offtime-ontime`. Then combine all these times.

Comment: This actually helped.. Thanks Anish!

Comment: @Anish Anne It would be helpful if you gave a code example.